# SP 2013 In-place search returns all list items after April 2017 CU

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

We're fighting with an issue after upgrading our SharePoint 2013 Farm to [April 2017 CU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3178730/april-11-2017-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2013-kb3178730) (15.0.4919.1003).

The in-place search seems not to filter at all. Instead all list items are shown - regardless of the search-term.

The list of things we've tried so far:

- Executed the SharePoint Config Wizzard (without error)
- Started a full crawl
- Ensured that all relevant managed properties are marked as searchable
- Restarted any kind of services or machine that could (or could not) be related
- Checking the event log and ULS logs (the're looking good to me)

Any solution we have found so far were targeting issues where the in-place search returns an empty search result.

The previous version was 15.0.4797.1000.

Is there any known issue with this update that could explain this behaviour?

Comment: did you run the SharePoint Config wizard after the CU Installation on all servers? are you seeing any error in the event log / ULS log?

Comment: Yes we've ran the wizard without seeing any error.

Comment: any clue from logs? did you restarted the search service?

Comment: No I didn't see any error either in the event log nor the uls log. The global search works by the way. We've reproduced the behaviour by upgrading a dev machine to the mentioned CU. Before the update the in-place search works fine but after the update the search shows always the full list.

Comment: But it is possible that I oversee something because I've no clue what exactly I'am searching for.

Comment: have you checked this before applying the CU? from which version u install this cu? I am thinking about opening a case with MSFT on this

Comment: The previous version was 15.0.4797.1000. Opening an case at MSFT would be the next step. I was hoping that maybe this is a known issue.